# pandas: How to convert a string to datetime?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a [CSV file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/tb4yc3lm3gg3j22/out.csv) in which I am trying to convert the `date` column to `dd/mm/yyyy` format using the below code but I am still struggling with `unconverted data remains`.

A few sample data-records from the `CSV`-file
    hotel,author,review,date,Overall,Value,Rooms,Location,Cleanliness,Check in/front desk,Service,Business,r9
    in,everywhereman2 ,Old seattle getaway This was Old World Excellence at it's best.THIS is the place to stay at when visiting the historical area of Seattle. Your right on the water front near the ferry's and great sea food restrauntsand still with'in walking distance for great blues and jazz music. The staff for this hotel are excellentthey make you feel right at home. The breakfast was great.We did'nt have to travel far to have a good cup of JOE and a light meal to start our adventurous day off into one of the most beautifull city's in america. This hotel is in an area that makes it easy to get to any place you want to go and still find your way back I highly recomend this hotel for your next visit to seattle.   ,Jan 6 2009 ,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,
    in,RW53 ,Location! Location?       view from room of nearby freeway   ,Dec 26 2008 ,3,4,3,2,4,3,-1,-1,

Can you, please, help me to point out my mistake?

I am reading the file in RSS and then:

```
import time 
for end_date in rss['date']:
    end_date     = end_date.split(" ")
    end_date[-1] = end_date[-1][:4]
    end_date     = " ".join(end_date)
    conv         = time.strptime( end_date,"%b %d %Y" )
    time.strftime( "%d/%m/%Y", conv )
rss['date']
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried your data and the following worked for me without having to do post-processing:

```
In [17]:

df =pd.read_csv(r'c:\data\out.csv', parse_dates=['date'])
df.dtypes

Out[17]:
hotel                          object
author                         object
review                         object
date                   datetime64[ns]
Overall                         int64
Value                           int64
Rooms                           int64
Location                        int64
Cleanliness                     int64
Check in/front desk             int64
Service                         int64
Business                        int64
r9                             object
dtype: object
```

Comment: thank you.:) how to convert the same in the csv file permanently to dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: @miku sorry what do you mean?

Comment: If you mean how do you specify the format when you write to csv then  you can specify the the format of dates that are written out by using the `date_format` argument of the `to_csv` method. In this case it would be `date_format='%d/%m/%Y'`

Comment: Sorry for vague format of my question: I meant, having data in the CSV already, how can I change the format of the date column via program code.

Comment: @miku if the data is strings and you want to convert to datetime after loading from csv then `pd.to_datetime(df['date'], '%d/%m/%Y')` should work, if it is already datetime and you want to change the display format then you convert the datetime to a string using `datetime.strftime` so `df['date_str'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))` should work.